# $3 X^3 + 4 Y^3 + 5 Z^3$ has roots in all $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\mathbb{R}$ but not in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

This is an exercise in my textbook in a chapter about the Hasse-Minkowski-theorem:

> Show that the polynomial $3 X^3 + 4 Y^3 + 5 Z^3$ has a non-trivial root in $\mathbb{R}$ and all $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Show that it has only the trivial root in $\mathbb{Q}$.

I don't know, at the first sight, this seems like a pretty hard exercise, especially the second part. Is it doable? Do you have any tips how to start?

Or should I simply skip it? Because I don't see how this exercise helps me to understand/apply the Hasse-Minkowski-theorem.

Comment: It helps us understand something beyond Hasse-Minkowski: it tells us the local-global philosophy is not as powerful (at least as we might initially conceive it) as an optimist would have wanted, because the logical extension from HM for quadratics to cubics fails. By the way, this polynomial is known as Selmer's example. See [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/selmerexample.pdf) for KCd's blurb on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical counterexample to Hasse-Minkowski, due to Selmer. The solution of the second part is indeed difficult. For a detailed proof see, for example, Chapter $7$ of the thesis of [Arnélie Schinck](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.collectionscanada.gc.ca%2Fobj%2Fs4%2Ff2%2Fdsk3%2Fftp04%2FMQ64047.pdf&ei=BcswVZqRK8zhap-EgNgN&usg=AFQjCNEFwqWeiXotrKxJNnneGlefvn6sjw&bvm=bv.91071109,d.d2s). 
However, the first part is quite easy, and goes as follows: we can explicitly list a solution for each $\mathbb{Q}_p$, including for $\mathbb{Q}_{\infty}=\mathbb{R}$:
$$
(x,y,z)=(-1,(3/4)^{1 /3},0),(0,(5/4)^{1/3},-1),(5,-2(15/4)^{1/3},-3),(-1,0,(3/5)^{1/3}).
$$
All solutions exist in $\mathbb{R}$, and *at least one* exists in a given $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: I now solved the easy part (for $\mathbb{Q}_p$) myself, but for the general case $p\geq 7$ I did it differently, by determining when $3$ is a cube modulo $p$ (that's iff $p \equiv 0, 2 \bmod 3$) and then treating the cases separately. So $(5, -2(15/4)^{1/3}, -3)$ is the solution for $p \geq 7$?